# java get inserted row ID

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, rowid

I am having a problem with retrieving the inserted rows id when using java + mysql with jdbc.Driver.

```
public Diak create(Diak diak) throws Exception
    {
        Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

        String SQL = "{ CALL DiakCreate(?, ?) }";

        PreparedStatement  stmt = connection.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setString(1, diak.Nev);
        stmt.setInt(2, diak.Kreditek);

        int affectedRows  = stmt.executeUpdate();

        //ellenorizzuk, hogy van e modositott record
        if (affectedRows == 0)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Failure");
        }

        //kikeressuk a generalt ID-t
        ResultSet generatedKeys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (generatedKeys.next())
        {
            diak.Id = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SQLException("Failure");
        }

        return  diak;
}
```

I tried some solutions that I found on the internet.
The record has been inserted in the table, but exception has been thrown and no Id is set to my response object.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the correct library imported for the PreparedStatement. It should be java.sql.Statement and not jdbc, a common mistake.

If that is correct, check [PreparedStatement Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to see how can you use executeUpdate(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys) in this context. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using java.sql.Statement.

Comment: I wanted to point that out some compilers automatically loads the wrong library and it is a frustrating thing. I don't know what is wrong then, honestly, but I think there is a way to use executeUpdate with the GeneratedKeys, you can check the interface I tagged. I hope that helps, otherwise I don't know what is going on. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

java:

```
public Diak create(Diak diak) throws Exception
        {
            Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

        String SQL = "{ CALL DiakCreate(?, ?, ?) }";

        CallableStatement  stmt = connection.prepareCall(SQL);
        stmt.setInt(1, diak.Id);
        stmt.setString(2, diak.Nev);
        stmt.setInt(3, diak.Kreditek);

        ResultSet resultSets  = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (resultSets.next())
        {
            diak.Id = resultSets.getInt(1);
        }


        return  diak;
    }
```

MySQL procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DiakCreate(OUT paramId INT, IN paramName VARCHAR(255), IN paramKreditek INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
          Diak (Nev, Kreditek)
    VALUES
        (paramName, paramKreditek);


    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as paramId;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```